# PostgreSQL takes 99,9% I/O?

Tags: postgresql, performance

Please, look at this screenshot of `iotop` tool output (Linux). There is long-running batch update process on table with 20+ million rows. Does it mean that postgres is limited by I/O disk performance?

[image]

Comment: So, data modification is I/O intensive, yes.  And Postgres may be limited by it, yes - however, seeing 99% I/O might simply mean the modifications got all the available resources, because nothing else does anything currently.  Do you experience problems elsewhere on the same machine?

Comment: @dezso No, I don't. This server is only for postgresql. But data updating (which includes mostly UPDATE and DELETE ops) is really slow. Database is already tuned as in various manuals described.

Comment: Which tables does your batch process update? Do they have a lot of indexes? Those are known to improve SELECTs (when properly done) but have a bad impact on UPDATEs and DELETEs. Have a look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/populate.html  for ideas to improve your batch.

Comment: @Andremoniy In this case, it would be interesting to see your batch job(s) that are slow.  Also, you mention 'Database is already tuned as in various manuals described' - add the relevant part of your configuration to your question.  Also, some understanding about the HW setup could help, too.  For example, are you on a VM of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, we'd have to know your hardware and how to interpret what iotop is reporting.  Not exactly on topic in this forum.  Taking a giant guess, assuming you're using something like ordinary SATA hardware, the answer would be No.  A single SATA drive is capable of something like 100 MB/s; you're seeing (on the first line) about 5% of that.  Before I'd credit the disk, I'd have to explain the other 95%.

In approaching Database performance problems, it's always a good idea to start with the DBMS itself, especially physical table design.  Work from the top down: DDL, DML, triggers, indexes, partitioning.  Once you're sure you have the DBMS's house in order, you can look at what the DBMS demands from the OS.  You can look at the depth of the I/O queues, I/O operation/second and how memory is being used.  More RAM is hardly ever harmful; a DBMS can use RAM to avoid I/O.

The reason to work this way is technical, not political.  Errors (or suboptimal choices) at the high levels can drive orders of magnitude in performance.  One index can mean the difference between O(n^2) and O(log n) performance, a matter hours versus seconds.  The further down you go, the harder it is to measure performance, and the more expensive to rectify.  Not to mention that any new machine capacity can quickly be absorbed by new bad SQL.